# Programming a Calendar Client on a Raspberry Pi

Tags: sharepoint, raspberry-pi, office365

I am an IT intern, tasked with creating a digital calendar for office use. My budget is small, so what I have is a 21" wall-mounted HDTV, and a Raspberry Pi with a Wifi adapter. The problem, is the team I am creating this for, already has a group calendar, hosted on their Office365 team site (which I have admin access to). The calendar used, is the built-in Calendar App, due to their primary usage of the online client for Outlook, rather than the desktop client (which has more sharing options). Each team member is then treated as an overlay, giving them their own color for events and such to keep the calendar readable.This team is not very technology adept, so drastically changing what they are currently using is highly undesirable.

What i would like to do, is use the Raspberry Pi to grab the calendar information from the team site, and then convert the data into a desktop client I build to be easily displayed on the connected TV, even when connection is interrupted. Further more, since the TV is not touch-enabled, I would like to be able to control the client from a company iPad, that would allow viewers to see Week or Day views, as apposed to strictly month views.

From poking around the calendar, and the web it appears the calendar is stored as a sharepoint list? There does not seem to be any other format that I can export or pull from the calendar, just a url to visit it, presumably containing the sharepoint list. My only other form of output is an RSS feed for the calendar.

My background is mostly in embedded systems work, and scientific computing. Thus I have never worked with sharepoint lists, or really anything this web based. I do however, feel comfortable with my ability to build the client to hold the calendar, I just need help getting that info from the web..

All I'm looking for is some direction or guidance on how I might pull the information from the team calendar/sharepoint list so I can convert it for client use. If I can provide any other information, please let me know.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SharePoint online provide the REST interfaces, you get can get the data via [REST](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj860569%28v=office.15%29.aspx). As I checked online, raspberry-pi supports REST.

Calendar is a list on SharePoint, with the REST API, you can [get the list by title](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn292552%28v=office.15%29.aspx), and and the the items in it, then you can show the content in our client.